# Questions about the xgb.cv and GridSearchCV

Tags: boosting

I am using the `xgboost` package in python to do predictive modelling problems. I encounter the following two questions:

First, I've specified a set of values for those hyper parameters and run cross validation

```
params1 = {
'max_depth':5,
'min_child_weight':1,
'learning_rate':0.1,
'gamma': 0,
'subsample':0.8,
'colsample_bytree':0.8,
'objective': 'binary:logistic',
'silent': 1,
'scale_pos_weight':1,
'nthread': 4,
}
num_rounds = 1000
hist = xgb.cv(params1, Dtrain, num_rounds, nfold=10, metrics={'error'},early_stopping_rounds = 50, seed=seed)
hist
```

[image]

**My question is:** does the `xgb.cv` do the following thing: for each value of the `num_rounds` (starting from 0 or 1?), it actually runs a 10-fold cv and outputs both the mean error of test and train? And here as we have 10 numbers for both train and test error, we could obtain the standard deviation of them. We know that the boost algorithm works as follows: it fits a simple tree in round 0 (or 1?), then in the next round, it fits another simple tree to the residual generating from the previous round, so on and so forth. Thus, it looks to me that this `xgb.cv` not only does cross validation, it also performs a hyper parameter tunning process for the `num_round` variable? Because, if it is just for cross validation, then it should just run the cv for the model with `num_round=1000` as I specified, but here it seems that it does cv for each value of `num_round=0,1,2,3,....`. And based on the early stopping rule, it finds the "optimal" value of `num_round`, in this example, it is 8, given all the other hyper parameters fixed.

Then, I found that `sklearn` package as a `GridSearchCV` to conduct the hyper parameter tunning process. Then I input **exactly** the same value of the above hyper parameters into `GridSearchCV`, I want to verify that these two methods agree with each other and they should. However, the result does NOT support this conjecture

```
params_fixed = {
'silent': 1,
'scale_pos_weight':1,
'nthread': 4,
'objective': 'binary:logistic'
}
params_grid = {
'learning_rate': [0.1],
'n_estimators':[8],
'max_depth':[5],
'min_child_weight':[1],
'gamma':[0],
'subsample':[0.8], 
'colsample_bytree':[0.8] 
}
bst_grid = GridSearchCV(
estimator=XGBClassifier(**params_fixed, seed=seed),
param_grid=params_grid,
cv=10,
scoring='accuracy'
)
bst_grid.grid_scores_
```

[image]

Note that it first correctly recognize that there is only one set of value of those hyper parameters to search. It reports `mean:0.82604`. I believe, for the set of hyper parameters I've specified, this `GridSearchCV` runs a 10 fold cv, which gives him the average accuracy rate 0.82604 **but this number does not agree with any one of those numbers above in the table that are subtracted by 1. ** As I fixed the `seed`. I could not come up with any other source of randomness.